# modify the values achieved through group_Concat in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I have the following [table a]

```
id     res1     res2     

1       a        f
1       b        f
1       b        f
1       c        f
2       e        g 
2       e        g
2       e        g
2       f        g
```

I'm getting the following after doing a group_concat

```
select 
  id, 
  group_concat(case when cnt = 1 then res1 else concat(cnt, ' ', res1) end) as r1,
  group_concat(case when cnt = 1 then res2 else concat(cnt, ' ', res2) end) as r2

from 
(
  select id, res1,res2, count(*) as cnt
  from [table a]
  group by id, res1,res2
) t
group by id;


id      r1          r2

1      a,2 b,c     f,2 f,f
2      3 e,f       3 g,g
```

**The res1 column is coming fine BUT res2 column is duplicating the res1 column.
Basically i want to print the value of how many times a character occurs before the character.
.I want in the following format..**

```
id     r1          r2

1      a,2 b,c     4 f
2      3 e,f       4 g
```

How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would approach this is to do two rollups/aggregations, using two separate subqueries for the `res1` and `res2` columns.  The first aggregation is over `id` *and* `res1` (or `res2`), and obtains the counts for each letter or word.  Then, aggregate again, this time only over the `id`, to obtain a comma separated string for each `id`.  Finally, join these subqueries together to obtain the final result.

```
SELECT
    t1.id, t1.r1, t2.r2
FROM
(
    SELECT t.id, GROUP_CONCAT(res1agg ORDER BY res1) AS r1
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            id,
            res1,
            CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN res1
                 ELSE CONCAT(CAST(COUNT(*) AS CHAR(50)), res1) END AS res1agg
        FROM yourTable
        GROUP BY id, res1
    ) t
    GROUP BY t.id
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t.id, GROUP_CONCAT(res2agg ORDER BY res2) AS r2
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            id,
            res2,
            CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN res2
                 ELSE CONCAT(CAST(COUNT(*) AS CHAR(50)), res2) END AS res2agg
        FROM yourTable
        GROUP BY id, res2
    ) t
    GROUP BY t.id
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: 1+ good one. I have also thought to make sub query.  But for me it take times

Comment: can u explain how the cast functinality works for this code:

Comment: CONCAT(CAST(COUNT(*) AS CHAR(50)), res1)

Answer (score 0):

Just added 2 more conditions in your query without using more inner queries.

Try this:-

```
input:-

CREATE TABLE Table1 (id INT, res1 varchar(20), res2 varchar(20));
insert into Table1  values(1, 'a', 'f');
insert into Table1  values(1, 'b', 'f');
insert into Table1  values(1, 'b', 'f');
insert into Table1  values(1, 'c', 'f');
insert into Table1  values(2, 'e', 'g');
insert into Table1  values(2, 'e', 'g');
insert into Table1  values(2, 'e', 'g');
insert into Table1  values(2, 'f', 'g');

Query:-


 Select t.id,group_concat(case when cnt = 1 then res1 else concat(cnt, ' ', res1) end) as r1,
 case when id=1 then trim(concat(sum(case when id = 1 then cnt end),' ',res2)) 
 else trim(concat(sum(case when id = 2 then cnt end),' ',res2)) end as r2
 from
 (
  select id, res1,res2,count(*) as cnt
  from table1 a
  group by id, res1,res2
 ) t
 group by t.id

My Output:-
    id  r1        r2
    1   a,c,2 b  4 f
    2   f,3 e    4 g
```

Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: @goonemike Can you try this?

Comment: ..Its showing 0 value before the character for all the rows in r2

Comment: @gonnermike It was working for me. I have put the complete code with input and output now. I have also removed the else 0 condition from the code which was not required and also added trim to remove spaces if that's what you are getting. Can you try again

Comment: @goonernike I have tried in sql fiddle also, this is the below given link . Its working over there also. Check this link out    http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2dbd82/1/0